# Write a data frame to worksheet using win32com in Python

Tags: python, dataframe, win32com

I want to print out the whole data frame into an excel workbook using win32com.client.

It works fine with single values or arrays, however when I try to copy and paste the whole data frame with dimension x * y, it has errors like:

```
TypeError: Objects for SAFEARRAYS must be sequences (of sequences), or a buffer object.
```

I'm wondering if there is a way to output the data frame. Thanks in advance.

My code that arises that error above:

```
sel = ws.Range('B11:O72')
sel.Value = db[:]
```

I'm doing this because printing one by one is quite slow.

Comment: So db is a  list that represents a 2d array?

Comment: db is a pandas dataframe of dimension greater than 1

Answer (score 7):

Hope this can help answer your question:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import win32com.client as MyWinCOM

# Book2.xlsx must already be open
xl = MyWinCOM.GetObject(None, "Excel.Application")
wb = xl.Workbooks("Book2.xlsx")
ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")


d = {'time' : pd.Series([1., 2., 3., 4.], index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']),
     'legnth' : pd.Series([4., 5., 6., 7.], index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

StartRow = 1
StartCol = 1
ws.Range(ws.Cells(StartRow,StartCol),# Cell to start the "paste"
         ws.Cells(StartRow+len(df.index)-1,
                  StartCol+len(df.columns)-1)
         ).Value = df.values

# OR
StartRow = 1
StartCol = 5
ws.Range(ws.Cells(StartRow,StartCol),# Cell to start the "paste"
         ws.Cells(StartRow+len(df.index)-1,
                  StartCol+len(df.columns))# No -1 for the index
         ).Value = df.to_records()
```

Comment: Thanks this really helps! I think I didnt add the ".values" and that causes the problem.